# different views for products magento

Tags: html, magento, view

how do I get magento 1.7 to render a view.phtml for bundled products and view.phtml for simple products or vice versa?

Basically how do I go about doing different views for different product types?

Answer (score 0):

I am also still new to this, if someone has a better way than what i would of done them please post. (I can learn from it also..)

But i would use ***one*** view.phtml file and put this around the code you would like to use for a bundled view

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "bundle"){ ?>
                <div class="product-view"> ... </div>

            <?php  } else { ?> 
                <div class="product-view"> ... </div>
            <?php  } ?>
```